# Should I use assert to verify a third party function?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I use some third party function which based on the filter returns specified number of objects:

```
//void GetObjects(std::vector<T>&, Filter, int /*objectsNumber*/)

GetObjects(vec, filter, 1);

if(vec.empty())
{
   throw ObjectNotFound();
}

assert(vec.size() == 1);
```

Should I use assert like above ? Is it a typical assert scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

How to handle errors in your program depends on you, and on your program nature.

In a production environment, you usually try not to assert because then it means your application dies. In other cases, the process that executes your program would realize your program died and then restart it.

If it's just for learning/training, asserting with a proper message is a good way to find your problem easily and fast.

Bottom line - it's really up to you. There's no right or wrong here.

If you do want to assert, usually you do it only when some very basic invariant/condition is not met, when your program just cannot know how to proceed from this point.

Comment: "In a production environment, you usually try not to assert because then it means your application dies" - one could argue that it is *better* to take the program down (die/crash) when the world has gone pear-shaped, rather than continue on in a broken world which may cause all sorts of bigger problems..

Comment: True, this is why it's *usually*. And if the world has gone pear-shaped I believe it's exactly a scenario where *a very basic invariant is not met*. This is why there's never one-general-answer to this question.

Comment: `assert` is *usually*  a no-op in production environments.

Comment: `assert()` is not for error handling, it's a debugging tool.

Comment: 1. Assertions and error-handling differ in many ways, but calling assertion a debug tool is just wrong. If you dumped your stack-trace when asserted - that can be a debug tool. 2. The OP asked about an *error* in his program and he wanted to know if he should use an assert to *handle* this error or not. The answer was given in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `assert()` is a macro that allows the checking code to be disabled for production code, so ensuring that the *foreign* function complies to the interface contract, it's a good custom to use assert to ensure the function specification are met.

Anyway, using mock instances and some Unit testing framework will give you better results, as it allows you to ensure the interface contract with finer exposure to *foreign* mistakes.  I recommend you **both**, and happy to see those ideas circulating over these environments :)